# Object are not valid as a React child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have read a few anwsers on SO but none seem to come across what I need.

I have a function:

```
const geoDataRTB = () => {
  return data.map((result) => result.request.buyerContext.request.geoData);
};
```

Which returns a json object.

```
"geoData": {
                        "type": "GPS",
                        "areaCode": "586",
                        "city": "MACOMB",
                        "country": "USA",
                        "metro": "505",
                        "latitude": "42.311859",
                        "longitude": "-85.579595",
                        "state": "MI",
                        "postalCode": "48042",
                        "bandwidth": "MOBILE",
                        "sic": "517312",
                        "domain": "MYVZW.COM",
                        "cityCode": 0
                    },
```

For example...currently I am returning `geoData.city` but id rather return the whole `geoDta` object instead. The end result is displayed via this

```
<section id='returnedData' className='mt-5 pb-5'>
        <h2 className={h2Styles}>result</h2>
        <div className='bg-gray-700 text-white rounded-md p-5 mt-5 '>
          {data.map((result, i) => (
            <div className='py-1'>
              <span className='text-xs text-gray-400 font-mono'>Capture {i} : </span>
              <span className='font-mono'>{result}</span>
              <br />
            </div>
          ))}
        </div>
      </section>
```

But when trying to return the `geoData` i get the object child error. Any suggestions on how to display the object? I have tried

```
const geoDataRTB = () => {
  return data.map((result) => result.request.buyerContext.request.geoData.toString());
};
```

But this just returns [Object, Object]

Comment: If you want to display `result` as `font-mono`'s content, you may change your code to: `<span className='font-mono'>{JSON.stringify(result)}</span>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display JSON as-is, usually you write something like:

```
<pre>
     {JSON.stringify(OBJECT, null, 2)}
</pre>
```

That will show a javascript object pretty printed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you want to display your data inside your monospace section, and not that you want to pass the data around for further manipulation or styling it in a different way.

If that's the case, you'll need to do:

```
const geoDataRTB = () => {
  return data.map(result => JSON.stringify(result.request.buyerContext.request.geoData));
};
```

Comment: Nice!! this works...but how could i format this so it looks like JSON? Can i manlipuate the string to look like JSON?

Comment: use a `<pre>` tag